# Setup gulp-sass to work like sass --watch

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I am trying to migrate a project to gulp-sass workflow. After reading some tutorials online, I have setup a very basic gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
      'sourcemap=none': true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});
```

I want to generate a `*.css` file from every `*.scss` file that doesn't begin with underscore.

My problem: with current gulpfile, gulp will detect changes on `.scss` files and rebuild ALL libraries, instead of building only the ones which have been affected by the change.

For example, I have 2 libs on my project:

- `lib1`, which @imports partials `p1` and `p2`
- `lib2`, which @imports partials `p2` and `p3`

If I edit partial `p1`, I want only `lib1` to be updated.

If I edit partial `p3`, I want only `lib2` to be updated.

If I edit partial `p2`, I want both `lib1` and `lib2` to be updated.

Current setup updates both libs on every edit that I make in any of the `*.scss` sources.

In other words, I would like gulp-sass to behave the same way as `sass --watch` does. Is this possible? How?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're targeting all scss files in your watch task:

```
gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
```

You can narrow it down to a subfolder or to specific files. You can breakdown your watch task into 2 parts, for example:

```
gulp.watch('scss/p1/**/*.scss', ['stylesP1', 'stylesP2']);
gulp.watch('scss/p2/**/*.scss', ['stylesP2', 'stylesP3']);
```

And then create 2 style tasks to match:

```
gulp.task('stylesP1', function() { /* Your task actions */ });
gulp.task('stylesP2', function() { /* Your task actions */ });
gulp.task('stylesP3', function() { /* Your task actions */ });
```

Comment: The way you are suggesting it, I would have to create additional gulp tasks for each css lib that I want to make. On the other hand, `sass --watch` is smart enough to understand `@import` directives and only generate the files that have been affected by the edit. This is what I am trying to achieve. I want to generate a `*.css` stylesheet for each `*.scss` filename which doesn't begin with an underscore and it needs to be done automatically and without updating all the other libraries which haven't been modified.

Comment: maybe something with the bang `gulp.src(['!sass/_*.scss'])`

Comment: The issue is not with matching the filenames, but with gulp knowing the dependencies of each file. When partial p1 is updated, gulp should know that lib1 depends on that file and lib2 doesn't.